# Servidores DNS con Amazon Web Services (AWS)

Tags: aws, amazon

Me acabo de migrar a Amazon Web Services con Lightsail y he creado una nueva instancia de Plesk Hosting Stack on Ubuntu. Ya tengo mi hosting con Plesk y he creado mi primer Website, ya subí los archivos y he creado la base de datos, pero resulta que mi dominio lo tengo con otro proveedor (https://mi.com.co/) y necesito modificar los registros DNS de mi dominio para que apunten a mi hosting que he creado con AWS.

¿Cómo hago esto?

Answer (score 0):

Pues básicamente tienes dos opciones:

1. Te apuntas la ip pública de tus instancias EC2 (las instancias de lightsail tienen una ip estática) y redireccionas el DNS a esa ip
2. Creas un dominio en Route53 para que apunte a tus instancias y redireccionas el otro dominio para que apunte al de AWS

Si tu pregunta va encaminada a cómo habría que modificar el dominio para que apunte a la ip de AWS ... no he usado nunca el proveedor que comentas, pero imagino que en el área de usuario tendrás la opción que buscas